# Tuning Hyperparameter Keras for Image Classification

Tags: python-3.x, keras, keras-layer

Is it possible for me to tuning hyperparameter in keras model using GridSearch or RandomizedSearch for Image Classification? I want to classify dogs and cats based on dogs and cats dataset.

```
class smallervggnet:
    @staticmethod
    def build(width, height, depth, classes, finalAct="softmax"):
        # initialize the model along with the input shape to be
        # "channels last" and the channels dimension itself
        model = Sequential()
        inputShape = (height, width, depth)
        chanDim = -1



        # if we are using "channels first", update the input shape
        # and channels dimension
        if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
            inputShape = (depth, height, width)
            chanDim = 1

        # CONV => RELU => POOL
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same",
            input_shape=inputShape))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))

        # (CONV => RELU) * 2 => POOL
        model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))

        # (CONV => RELU) * 2 => POOL
        model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))

        # first (and only) set of FC => RELU layers
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(1024))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))

        # softmax classifier
        model.add(Dense(classes))
        model.add(Activation(finalAct))

        # return the constructed network architecture
        return model
```

what i want to tuning is the neurons inside the Convolution layer or tuning Pooling layer.

```
param_grid = {'neurons':[4, 8, 16, 32, 64],
     'pooling': ['MaxPooling2D', 'AveragePooling2D', 'GlobalMaxPooling2D', 'GlobalAveragePooling2D']
     }
```

where param_grid should be put into grid search or randomized search. what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it´s possible to do that. 
The way to do this is using KerasClassifier from sci-kit learn.

```
clf = KerasBatchClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=epochs, shuffle=True)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, param_grid=parameters,return_train_score=False)
grid_result = grid.fit(X,y)
print(grid_result.best_score_)
print(grid_result.best_params_)
```

create_model is your build function, which accepts the parameters.

You should consider some things:

- you don´t have a validation after each epoch, no early stopping
- uses 10-fold cross validation (cv parameter), very time consuming
- Does not work with generators very well

To solve these problems, you can try to make a custom implementation of KerasClassifier, which I also did. In my approach I did only a 3-fold cross validation. I used 20% of the training data to utilize early stopping and I implemented it to deal with generators.

Comment: I already tried using the same query as you mention, but it didn't work. Because the X.shape i have is (80, 96, 96, 3) and Y.shape is (80, 2) which is the label dataset which i performed using MultiLabelBinarizer.